# matching braces from one case to another

Tags: equations, cases

How would you match the lines between two `cases` within the same `equation` environment? What I'm having is:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{rcases}
  \sum_{I=1}^{NP} K_h (x - x_I; x) \Delta x_I &= 1 \\
  \sum_{I=1}^{NP} \left(\frac{x - x_I}{h}\right) K_h (x - x_I; x) \Delta x_I &= 0 \\
  &\;\;\vdots \notag \\q
  \sum_{I=1}^{NP} \left(\frac{x - x_I}{h}\right)^n K_h (x - x_I; x) \Delta x_I &= 0
\end{rcases} =  
\begin{cases}
  M_0 (x) &= 1 \\
  M_1 (x) &= 1 \\
  &\;\;\vdots \notag \\
  M_n (x) &= 1 \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
```

This is the current output:[image]

Now I want to match the rows of the cases on the left with those on the right. I could do something ugly like adding `\vspace`, but is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: I think that ``\\q`` should be ``\\`` (no `q`).

Comment: @egreg yep that's a typo that I only spotted a bit too late... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `<stuffB>` to have the same height as `<stuffA>`, use `\vphantom{<stuffA>}<stuffB>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \left. \begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}r}
    \sum_{I = 1}^{NP} K_h (x - x_I; x) \Delta x_I = 1 \\
    \sum_{I = 1}^{NP} \Bigl( \frac{x - x_I}{h} \Bigr) K_h (x - x_I; x) \Delta x_I = 0 \\
    \vdotswithin{=}\phantom{0} \\
    \sum_{I = 1}^{NP} \Bigl(\frac{x - x_I}{h} \Bigr)^n K_h (x - x_I; x) \Delta x_I = 0
  \end{array} \right\} 
  = 
  \left\{\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}r}
    \vphantom{\sum_{I = 1}^{NP}} M_0 (x) = 1 \\
    \vphantom{\sum_{I = 1}^{NP}} M_1 (x) = 1 \\
    \vdotswithin{=}\phantom{1} \\
    \vphantom{\sum_{I = 1}^{NP}} M_n (x) = 1
  \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to suppress the whitespace padding on the sides of the `array` environments. That way, the tall curly braces will be typeset more snuggly to their respective `array` environments.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses two `aligned` environments, as well as (typographic) struts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \vdotswithin macro
\usepackage{mleftright} \mleftright % tighter spacing around large parentheses
\newcommand\tallstrut{\vphantom{\sum_{I=1}^{NP}}} % define a tall typographic strut

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
  \sum_{I=1}^{NP} K_h (x - x_I; x) \Delta x_I &= 1 \\
  \sum_{I=1}^{NP} \left(\frac{x - x_I}{h}\right) K_h (x - x_I; x) \Delta x_I &= 0 \\
  &\vdotswithin{=} \\
  q\sum_{I=1}^{NP} \left(\frac{x - x_I}{h}\right)^{\!n} K_h (x - x_I; x) \Delta x_I &= 0
\end{aligned} 
\right\} 
=  
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
  M_0 (x) &= 1  \tallstrut \\
  M_1 (x) &= 1  \tallstrut \\
          &\vdotswithin{=} \\
  M_n (x) &= 1  \tallstrut 
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```